# AWS Redshift "Query result is not ready, status: FINISHED"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

The error is:

```
Query result is not ready, status: FINISHED (Service: AmazonRedshift; Status Code: 400; Error Code: QueryNotFinished; Request ID: xxx)
```

when i run

```
 SELECT * FROM STL_LOAD_ERRORS ORDER BY 4 DESC LIMIT 100;
```